# Brute forcing the private key

Tags: python, cryptography, private-key, brute-force

I need to find x from the below equation

```
h = pow(g,x,p)
```

I have the values of

```
h = 400 digit number
g = 400 digit number
p = 400 digit number
```

I need to find the value of x.

All the values are very big.

I have incomplete x with 10 missing digits in it and they are not continuous missing digits.Index of all the missing digits is different.

I am using 10 for loops 
to replace that value every time to get H.It is taking too much time in python to do that.Is there anyway in which I can do it faster.

Comment: "It is taking too much time" - as it's supposed to. Hence the name, "bruteforce"

Comment: "bruteforce" does not ensure success.

Comment: Don't use python. It's that simple. Use something like C. Or maybe if you aren't too keen on getting rid of python altogether use Cython.

Comment: @MustacheMoses:python has pretty a pretty fast native biginteger implementation. GMP is faster, but not by much.

Comment: @zaph ... basically "bruteforce" means exhaustive key search ... since it is exhaustive, it means the complete search ensures success... but it just might take to long to complete any time soon, like within the lifetime of a human... or our sun ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Let me refine, a "bruteforce" search attempt does not ensure success because it may not complete in a meaningful time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `pow()` ten billion times. Instead, use it to calculate the first value of `h`, and then calculate each successive value by multiplying the previous value by `g` (or `g` raised to the appropriate power of 10 in the case where the missing digits are not at the end of `x`).

Here's a worked example that finds 7 missing digits in just a few seconds. It should give an answer for ten missing digits in a few hours. But as others have noted, you will get better performance by porting this code to another language like C.

```
h = 27029080272084173153635398406622455117429159185281491773519587480106092289627
g = 26376362132555166607008315364046996472951702119314003469217622667073785183917
p = 81593331324697655999776287731387256090095437693547587289127550085992860325943
x = 31952256647378403805884540140134925446045889939629675712565170000000381638216
                                 # The missing digits (3897858): ^^^^^^^
z = pow(g, x, p)                 # Initial value of h
d = pow(g, 10**9, p)             # Multiplier to get next value of h
while z != h:
    z = (z * d) % p
    x += 10**9                   # Increment x at position of last unknown digit

print(x)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If the missing digits are not consecutive, then you can still use a similar approach, but instead of incrementing x by the same amount each time, you'll need to keep tabs on which digits are changing at each step. For example given a number `.0.....0...0..`, where `0` represents a missing digit and `.` represents a known digit, you'll need to add `100` when incrementing the last unknown digit, `9999100` when the last unknown digit has reached 9, and `999990999100` when the last two unknown digits are both 9. It shouldn't be too hard to figure out the correct increments for any pattern of unknown digits.

```
.0.....0...0.. + 100
.0.....0...1.. + 100
.0.....0...2.. + 100
  :   :   :
.0.....0...8.. + 100
.0.....0...9.. + 9999100
.0.....1...0.. + 100
.0.....1...1.. + 100
  :   :   :
.0.....1...9.. + 9999100
.0.....2...0.. + 100
  :   :   :
.0.....9...9.. + 999990999100
.1.....0...0.. + 100
  :   :   :
```

This should run in a feasible amount of time with 10 unknown digits, but for a much faster solution, use the meet-in-the-middle approach suggested by James K Polk in the comments below.

Comment: FYI: I just tried solving the same problem with repeated calls to `pow()` and it took over 10 minutes to get the same result. So the successive multiplication approach is about 200 times faster.

Comment: Use baby steps-giant steps and get the answer in a few seconds.

Comment: Break the unknown exponent x into two pieces: base 10 digits or base 2 bits, I'm just going to use bits. So write x = (2^k)x1 + x0, where 0<=x1<2^k is the low order k bits of x. Now rewrite the equation as h=(g^((2^k)x1)(g^x0) mod p. Now "move" to x0 piece to the LHS, so get h * (g^(-x0)) = g^((2^k)x1) mod p. Now precompute the LHS for every possible x0 and save it in a lookup table, maybe a python dict for example. Now compute every possible value of the RHS and see if it's in the lookup table. It must work for at least one value. The work factor is about the square root of brute force.

Comment: @JamesKPolk OK, I think I see what you mean. So in the above example, x1=319522...517000 and x0=381638216 (assuming we're using base 10 and k=13)..... I'll have a go at writing some code for this when I find the time. Thanks :-)

Comment: Exactly, you want about the same number of unknown bits or digits on each side.

Comment: Missing Digits are not continuous.One missing digit is like 4th index then other is 10th and so on.

Comment: @thunder: That makes it more tedious programming-wise but doesn't change the computational complexity.